# Resize Textbox Programmatically in Telerik Report

Tags: telerik, resize, report

I have created a table then put a Textbox named "txtTextBox" into a cell of table. The width of the Textbox is 2 inch. In code I change width of Textbox like below
There are 2 case when report viewed:

Case 1: new width > designed width (2inch)

```
txtTest.Width = Unit.Inch(2.5); ==> The Textbox is showed longer. It is right
```

Case 2: new width < designed width (2inch)

```
txtTest.Width = Unit.Inch(1.5); ==> The Textbox is still showed with 2 inch. Expected it should shorter
```

[image]

how to resize column table fit with new width of Textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik doesn't allow width changes after items initialized. You must define your items programmatically instead of designer to do this.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/auto-resize-the-column-headers-of-the-telerik-reporting-table